# Scrolling to specific possiton on linked page

Tags: html

Is there a way to make a link that will scroll the visited page, say, 600 pixels from the top or the bottom?
And I'm not thinking about scrolling to an anchor...

I want to make a link about device support for iOS and the best results are on this page: https://www.apple.com/augmented-reality/
but the part about the device support is at the same bottom and there is no proper anhora or ID tag to scroll to.
So, wouldn't it  be great if I could write, for example:
href="https://www.apple.com/augmented-reality@bottom&600" or something to scroll to 600px from the bottom edge? Does anyone know if it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Chrome's feature "[Scroll to text fragment](https://web.dev/text-fragments/)" could help for this.

Just add `#:~:text={text}` to the url, where `{text}` is some text that should be highlighted and scrolled to.

In your example, this could look like this:
[https://www.apple.com/augmented-reality/#:~:text=Snapchat](https://www.apple.com/augmented-reality/#:%7E:text=Snapchat)

I don't know if this always works reliably, but it's the only way I can think of at the moment.
Edit: I just realized that the link doesn't work as expected on first try but when reloading...

Comment: That's a neat idea - it looks for a part of the text and selects it, so the page scrolls to that place.
Too bad it works only on chromium browsers and the downside is that if the text occurs in more than one place it shows the first one.

Thanks for the idea though. It's a really good tip